# Spring Cloud Contract EXPLICIT and WEBTESTCLIENT testMode

Tags: spring-webflux, junit5, spring-cloud-contract

I want to use Spring Cloud Contract to produce my contracts and verify them. I want to use Spring WebFlux and Junit5. This is my Controller:

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class HelloWorldPortRESTAdapter implements HelloWorldPort {

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello-world", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @Override
    public Mono<String> helloWorld() {
        return Mono.just("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

This is cloud contract maven plugin configuration:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <basePackageForTests>com.example.feedproviderapi.contract</basePackageForTests>
                    <testFramework>JUNIT5</testFramework>
                    <testMode>EXPLICIT</testMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But i don't know how base test class should look like. I tried this:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class BaseTestClass {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:" + this.port;
    }

}
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, it returns `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Then I changed `testMode` property in maven plugin to `WEBTESTCLIENT` and updated `BaseTestClass` like this:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BaseTestClass {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        RestAssuredWebTestClient.standaloneSetup(context);
    }

}
```

And again when I run `mvn clean install` now it returns:

```
You haven't configured a WebTestClient instance. You can do this statically

RestAssuredWebTestClient.mockMvc(..)
RestAssuredWebTestClient.standaloneSetup(..);
RestAssuredWebTestClient.webAppContextSetup(..);

or using the DSL:

given().
        mockMvc(..). ..
```

Btw I tried `RestAssuredWebTestClient.standaloneSetup(new HelloWorldPortRESTAdapter());` as well in my `BaseTestClass` but the result is same.

So how should I implement `BaseTestClass` regarding `EXPLICIT` and `WEBTESTCLIENT` testModes?

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled for 3 days, to makes RestAssuredWebTestClient works.

Thanks a llooottt for : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient

That's how i could do that:

```
@WebFluxTest
public class AnimeControllerIntegrTest{

    WebTestClient testClient;

    @Test
    public void get_RA() {

        testClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/animes").build();

        RestAssuredWebTestClient
                .given()
                .webTestClient(testClient)

                .when()
                .get()

                .then()
                .statusCode(OK.value())

                .body("name" ,hasItem("paulo"))
        ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spring cloud contract samples  https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_webflux_webtestclient

And junit5

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer_with_junit5

The

```
plugin 



<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <packageWithBaseClasses>com.example</packageWithBaseClasses>
                <testMode>WEBTESTCLIENT</testMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit-platform-surefire-provider.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And The base class for junit5

public abstract class BeerRestBase {

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    // remove::start[]
    RestAssuredWebTestClient.standaloneSetup(new ProducerController(personToCheck -> personToCheck.age >= 20));
    // remove::end[]
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I checked these samples before asking this question. I tried to implement a very simple example but i couldn't. Can you please tell me what is missing in my `BaseTestClass`?

Comment: Your test framework must be aligned with the redt assured setup. E.g. You have explicit but use webtestclient. Set it to webtestclient and that should work

Comment: Yes I did it. As I said in my question I changed it to webtestclient and updated `BaseTestClass` aligned with it. But at that time I got different error (i wrote that as well in my question).

Comment: Can you post a sample somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an `ApplicationContext` instance instead of `WebApplicationContext`.