# How to use WebTestClient to connect a http server?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

As javadoc of WebTestClient described: `This client can connect to any server over HTTP`.
But code below doesn't really request over http:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class HelloControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void test_hello() {
        webTestClient
            .get()
            .uri("http://localhost:8080/hello/World")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.name").isEqualTo("aaa");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_hello2() {
        webTestClient = webTestClient.mutate().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();// even this does not work
        webTestClient.get()
            .uri("/hello/World")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.name").isEqualTo("aaa");
    }
}
```

please help how to use WebTestClient to connect a http server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();
```

Thanks for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094850/13789176